# How to ignore meta* fields in Razl scripting

Tags: razl

So far we were able to sync content between environments through Razl tool(Manually). Now we need to create a Powershell script and automate this by using Sitecore Razl script engine. When I looked at the [documentation](https://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/razl/script.html), they have many methods for different operations.

But for my requirement, I need to ignore the common mod* metadata fields as shown in below Image.

[image]

When I tried to see the available methods, `Get-RazlDeepCompareResults` shows the exact difference but it doesn't have ability to ignore as I explained above. In order to achieve my requirement, do I need to GET each field and compare? Do anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement of ignoring specific metadata fields while syncing content using the Sitecore Razl script engine, you can use the Get-RazlDeepCompareResults cmdlet to get the differences, and then filter out the properties you want to ignore before performing the sync.

Here's an example of a PowerShell script to sync content while ignoring specific metadata fields:

```bash
# Load the Razl PowerShell module
Import-Module -Name "Sitecore.Razl.PowerShell"

# Connect to source and target Sitecore instances
$sourceConnection = Connect-RazlConnection -Url "https://source-instance-url" -Username "username" -Password "password"
$targetConnection = Connect-RazlConnection -Url "https://target-instance-url" -Username "username" -Password "password"

# Specify the IDs of the items you want to sync
$sourceItemId = "{source-item-id}"
$targetItemId = "{target-item-id}"

# Get the deep compare results
$compareResults = Get-RazlDeepCompareResults -SourceConnection $sourceConnection -SourceItemId $sourceItemId -TargetConnection $targetConnection -TargetItemId $targetItemId

# Define the metadata fields to ignore
$ignoreFields = @("__Revision", "__Updated", "__Updated by")

# Filter the compare results to exclude the ignored fields
$filteredResults = $compareResults | Where-Object { $_.SourceProperty.Name -notin $ignoreFields -and $_.TargetProperty.Name -notin $ignoreFields }

# Perform the sync using the filtered results
$syncResults = Sync-RazlItem -SourceConnection $sourceConnection -SourceItemId $sourceItemId -TargetConnection $targetConnection -TargetItemId $targetItemId -SyncFields $filteredResults

# Close the connections
Disconnect-RazlConnection -Connection $sourceConnection
Disconnect-RazlConnection -Connection $targetConnection
```

Replace the placeholders (like `source-instance-url`, `username`, `password`, `source-item-id`, and `target-item-id`) with the actual values for your Sitecore instances and items.

This script connects to the source and target Sitecore instances, gets the deep compare results, filters out the metadata fields you want to ignore, performs the sync using the filtered results, and then disconnects from the instances.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @Vadim. In your script you mentioned $fields = $sourceItem.Fields | Where-Object { $_.Key -notlike "mod*" } Do I need to mention all my columns here or mod* is enough?

Comment: @Yeshwanth If you are sure that you don't need all fields with prefix "_" you can use the following row

$fields = $sourceItem.Fields | Where-Object { $_.Key -notlike "_*" }

Comment: I have one more question here. Currently I am using RAZL Script to compare between environments and not Databases. Having said that, I am trying to use `Get-RazlItem` instead of `Get-Item`. But, `Get-RazlItem` is not displaying all fields except Shared and Versioned ones. So the question is How can i get all the fields using RAZL Script

Comment: @Yeshwanth as far as I know RAZL Get-RazlItem doesn't have -AllFields parameter, but you can try to achieve the same using vanilla Sitecore Powershell command GetItem. Updated an answer accordingly

Comment: I see that `New-ScriptSession` is not part of Sitecore Powershell Extensions. It is throwing me an error as `'New-ScriptSession' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`.

Comment: updated answer @Yeshwanth

Comment: Thank you @Vadim. I will definitely try it out.

Comment: no problems. Please, provide feedback after it

Comment: @Yeshwanth how are you? :)